# Getting user data from server in angular controller without exposing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've been trying to get user data from a rails controller to an angular controller:

In my `application.html.erb`, I define `User` like so:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.module('myModule').value('User', <%= @user.to_json.html_safe %>);
});
```

In my angular controller:

```
myModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
    $scope.user = User;
}]);
```

The problem with this is that it exposes the user data to the view. Is there a better way to do this?

I've also tried this approach:

In my module, I created a factory with a $resource object:

```
myModule.factory('User', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/users/:action', {},
    {
        'getUser': { method: 'GET', params: { action: 'fetch_user.json' }, isArray:true }
    });    
});
```

In my controller:

```
myModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
    $scope.user = User.getUser();

    // Also tried the following.
    // This will throw undefined errors in places that are trying to access $scope.user
    User.getUser({}, function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
    });
}]);
```

However, this either does not load the user data on time and is throwing `undefined` errors throughout my application or it will put every character of the result in it's own array container.

The `@user` variable is being returned as json from the server in the `users_controller.rb` so ideally, I would want to retrieve that and store it in `$scope.user`. The problem with this is that it requires the `username` to be passed as a parameter to retrieve the correct user's data.

How can I set `$scope.user` correctly and cleanly without exposing data?

Answer (score 0):

**Directive**

```
myModule.factory('User', function($http) {
    return {
        getUser: function () {
            // deferred object
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/fetch_user.json') {
                .success(function (data, status) {
                     deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                     deferred.reject("An error occured while trying to get users");
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
       }
    }
}
```

**Contoller:**

```
myModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
     User.getUser().then(function (data) {
         $scope.user = data;
     });
}]);
```

I'm assuming `/fetch_user.json` is the `url`, if not just replace it.

**Update**

Comment: @rabid_zombie you're really not giving me any constructive feedback. Have you solved it, is it working on not?